# How to Program xulrunner application to display output file or command line?

Tags: firefox, add-on, xulrunner

My question is in response to this article 
https://developer.mozilla.org/En/How_to_check_the_security_state_of_an_XMLHTTPRequest_over_SSL

I have downloaded and configured the xulrunner the only problem I'm getting to run javascript given in the link to display it output. Using xulrunner i want to know how can i produce an output as a headerless command-line program not gui.

```
   var httpRequest = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/xmlextr/xmlhttprequest;1"].createInstance();
   // Disable alert popups on SSL error 
   httpRequest.mozBackgroundRequest = true;
   httpRequest.open("GET", "https://developer.mozilla.org/", true); 
   httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {  
   if (httpRequest.readyState == 4) {
// Print security state of request
   dumpSecurityInfo(httpRequest.channel);
 }
     };

     httpRequest.send(null);
```

In the above code taken from the same link i want to see the output of function on my command screen or even a writing the information to file would do.

Do i have to change something in *.xul file extension.? I'm new to using xulrunner some help would be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

To print something to the console you use the [`dump()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.dump). If your code runs in the context of a window you will need to change `browser.dom.window.dump.enabled` preference to `true`. XPCOM components can simply call `dump()` without changing this preference.